# passing a constructor with template class arguments to a another function

Tags: c++

I have a class whose constructor has to be initialised with template class arguments. Now, I need to pass the constructor of this class to an another method in `main()`. But I am trying to do so, it throws an error and I not able to get the solution for it.

```
template<class K>

Class Student
{

    friend void printFunction();
    public:
    Student(K val)
    {std::cout<<val;}

};

void printFunction(Student object)
{

    ......

}

int main()
{

    Student <int> object(10);
    printFunction(object); //This line throws an error 

}
```

Here is the error message:

```
error: use of class template 'Student' requires template arguments
```

Answer (score 2):

There are several problems with your code. First and easy one is that you pass class name `Student` to the call of your `printFunction`. You should call `printFunction(object)` instead.

Second, for `printFunction` to accept an instance of template class `Student`, you need to make it template as well. See working example below.

```
#include <iostream>

template<class K>
class Student;

template<class K>
void printFunction(Student<K> object)
{
    std::cout << object.val;
}


template<class K>
class Student
{
    friend void printFunction<>(Student<K>);

public:
    Student(K val) : val(val) {}

private:
    K val;
};



int main()
{
    Student<int> object(10);
    printFunction(object); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks, passing `printFunction(Student);` was just a mistake while posting my question here. Your solution worked but I did not understand the requirement of declaring `template <class T>` above friend `void printFunction(Student<T>);` inside Class. Why can't we just write `friend void printFunction(Student<K>);.`. I know then the compiler throws error but why??

Comment: @user2756695 I edited the code to use a forward declaration of the `Student` class and a friend specialization of `printFunction`. Does this answer your question?

Comment: @user2756695 if you made error while posting question - then it is time to correct it - so we would know what is your real question?